# A parallel version of Kahn's algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to make a parallelised version of Kahn's Algorithm using OpenMP. Because i'm quite new to OpenMP i don't know if i made the parallelisation correctly. The pseudocode from which i drew inspiration is the bellow

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements 
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edge 

while S is non-empty do     
    remove a node n from S     
    add n to tail of L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
         remove edge e from the graph
         if m has no other incoming edges then
             insert m into S 

if graph has edges then
    return error   (graph has at least one cycle) 
else      
    return L       (a topologically sorted order)
```

My problem is that my serial version, which is the same as bellow, with the exception of the pragma commands and the thread related commands, is faster than my parallel version. I measure the time using the gettimeofday() function. Is there something wrong with my code? I also compiled the code using -O0 and -O3 in both cases.

```
void TopSort(int rows, int columns, int matrix[][columns], list graph[], list S[], int L[]){
    int i, j, sum_S = 1, count = 0, k = 1;
    int start, end, threads, elements, id;

    while(sum_S != 0)   //While S is non - empty do
    {
        printf("\n\n--------- Iteration no. %d ---------", k);  //Print the iteration number
        k++;

        for(i = 1; i < rows; i++){  //With each iteration
            int sum = 0;        //we calculate the new degree of each node after deletion
        for(j = 1; j < columns; j++)
            sum = sum + matrix[j][i];

        if(graph[i - 1].id != 0)    //If the node hasn't been deleted
            graph[i - 1].degree = sum;  //We update the degree
    }


    printf("\nGraph: \n");  //and print the graph
    print(graph, rows);

    sum_S = 0;  //We set the sum_S to 0 to calculate it with the remaining nodes
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) shared(rows, columns, S, L, graph, matrix, count) private(i, id, threads, elements, start, end)
    {
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        threads = omp_get_num_threads();
        elements = (rows-1)/threads;
        start = elements*id;

        if(id != (threads - 1))
            end = start + elements;
        else
            end = (rows-1);

        for(i = start; i < end; i++)
            #pragma omp critical
            if(graph[i].degree == 0){   //If there is a node with no incoming edges
                #pragma omp task
                {
                    printf("thread %d of %d entering critical region\n", id, threads);
                    S[count].id = graph[i].id;  //add it's id to S
                    S[count].degree = graph[i].degree;//and the appropriate degree
                    L[count] = S[count].id; //and add the node from S to L
                    graph[i].id = 0;    //Delete the node from the graph list
                    graph[i].degree = INT_MAX;  //and set it's degree to infinity(INT_MAX)
                    for(j = 1; j < columns; j++)
                        matrix[i+1][j] = 0; //Also delete the node from the graph matrix
                    count+=1;
                    printf("exiting critical region\n");
                }
            }
    }

    printf("\nS: \n"); //Print the S list
    print(S, rows);

    for(i = 0; i < (rows - 1); i++)//Recalcute the ID sum of nodes inside S list
        sum_S = S[i].id + sum_S;

    for(i = 0; i < (rows - 1); i++){    //Reset S
        S[i].id = 0;    //by setting the ID to zero
        S[i].degree = INT_MAX;  //and the degree to infinity
    }

    printf("\nTopological order: ");    //Print the current topological order

    for(i = 0; i < (rows - 1); i++)
        if(L[i] != 0)//by printing the nodes with non-zero IDs 
            printf("%d --> ", L[i]);
    }


    for(i = 0; i < (rows - 1); i++)
        if(L[i] == 0){  //If the L list has a node with a zero ID
            printf("\n\nError! Circle detected! No topological order!\n");  //there is a circle inside the graph
            break;  //and so there isn't a topological order
        }
    else if(i == (rows - 2))
        printf("END\n");
}
```

Comment: How long do both versions take?  Keep in mind that there is quite a bit of overhead involved to spin up new threads.

Comment: Well the differences between them are about 0.02 seconds. Could this be accounted to the time taken to create new threads?

Comment: Certainly possible.  What matters is how long it takes to start a new thread vs the total runtime of the algorithm.  For example if the whole thing takes 10 minutes to run and there is only 0.02 seconds difference, then there is probably something else going on.

Comment: Actually sorry, the whole process for the serial version takes about 0.05 seconds, while for the parallel version it takes about 0.2 seconds, which is quite the difference..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution of Directed Acyclic Graph of tasks in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354899/execution-of-directed-acyclic-graph-of-tasks-in-parallel)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that all the computational work is put in a critical section.
Since the critical section serializes operations, you should not expect any speed up regarding the sequential version. In practice, it can even be slower.

Moreover, I am not sure this code is actually correct. Indeed, you use the `#pragma omp task` in a critical section. The runtime may or may not execute the task directly or defer its execution (see Section 2.10 of the [OpenMP 5.0 specification](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf)). In the first case, your code seems correct, but it will not run faster than the sequential version. In the second case, the thread entering the critical section submits a task and then leave the critical section so that other threads can submit also further tasks and execute *task of other threads* in parallel. In this case, there are data races in the executed tasks because `count` is shared and the increment unprotected as well as the access to `S[count].id` and others.

You need to redesign your parallel algorithm. Working on graphs in parallel is not simple, especially when the structure of the graph need to be mutated in parallel. I do not expect this approach to scale well (or being faster than an optimized sequential algorithm) even by using fine-grained locks or atomic instructions carefully. I advise you to look for parallel topological sorts in the state of the art. You can find some very interesting solutions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Parallel_algorithms).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try a different approach then and see what happens.